# Why does MySQL always give error access denied even though user exists?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm trying to simply run `php artisan migrate --seed` on a new Laravel project but everytime I try, I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'appuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I check my database config file and the correct username and password for the database are there.

I check MySQL Workbench, and the correct user is there with all the schema privileges for the same password.

I tried adding the user with privileges under `%`, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` but same access denied error.

I ran a quick check to make sure Laravel was selecting the right environment for the database connection details and it is.

I've created users hundreds of times and never had this problem. This all started after I updated to the latest MySQL Workbench 6.1.7 after the older version stopped working correctly on Windows 8. Sadly, I don't have the option to even go back and test if the old version fixes the problem since it won't work at all.

At this point I can't get any new database users to connect.

The database server is up and running, and every other previously existing user still connects just fine.

Here is the [my.ini file](https://cloudup.com/cfHI3CpypCA).

Any ideas? I'm hoping I'm just tired and missing something obvious here.

Comment: Can you provide the my.cnf file with mysql configuration? probably it can help.

Comment: @vodolaz095 Added a link to the my.ini file.

Comment: I also just tried executing `grant all on app_db.* to 'appuser'@'localhost';` but it does not actually update the `user_privileges` table. A similar query of `mysql.users` confirms the privileges remain unchanged despite granting while logged in as root.

Comment: Something I missed is a warning whenever I connected the database stating Windows `does not properly support the selected lower_case_table_names option value`. I've never seen this warning before now. Just on a hunch, I removed the underscore in the database name `app_db` so that it was now just `app`. When I tried to grant all privileges to `app` for `appuser` it was successful. Why this made a difference I don't know because `lower_case_table_names=2` is the correct value for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

by reading the config file.

```
[client]
password    = mysql
port        = 3306
socket      = "{$path}/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

i think you need to comment the string with default password. Probaby it affects something.
I have recent MariaDB, and the password string is commented out in every config file example

Comment: upd: do you have Windows PC that ran this DB? If yes, check the file\folder permissions for tables, probably they are readonly to user running the database client